Configuring Supabase for Local Production Use on an Offline Device
I am working on a project that involves deploying Supabase on a device isolated from the internet. This device will serve a web application accessible to clients over a local network, with Supabase handling data storage.
Previously, I've used Supabase in a local development environment. However, I've encountered issues where my tables and data were unexpectedly deleted.
Is there a method to configure Supabase for a local production setting, ensuring data persistence and stability without internet connectivity?
Thank you!
